# Velocity of the object in Binary system

Tags: star, gravity

[image: Example]

how to i can calculate the velocity of the object? If i know the distance of the object from the center of mass, and i know distance between the two (identical) ellipse center... (the two object has the same mass) and of course we know the ellipses semi-major and -minor axis

Comment: You will need some more information, eg a point in the orbit.  But the generalized problem is converting Kelperian elements to position and velocity.  Search for that, and you should find some good explanations.

Comment: One of the most useful equations in orbital mechanics is the [vis-viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation) Also, see answer(s) to [Orbital speeds of Components of Binary System](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/49418/7982)

Comment: I want to know the values of orbital parameters that make siuch system stable.

Comment: The orbit is stable if the sum of potential & kinetic energies is negative. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy which is linked from the vis-viva article.

Comment: You had a possibly acceptable answer that was deleted because your question is confusing. Do you want the velocity (title) or the speed? If there are additional requirements then put them in the question, not in comments.

Comment: Well i want to know velocity but sometimes i confuse with speed.

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/533832/123208